# Prove the inequality - inequality involving surds

Tags: inequality, radicals

Prove that for $r$ greater than or equal to 1:

$\displaystyle 2(\sqrt{r+1} - \sqrt{r}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} < 2(\sqrt{r}-\sqrt{r-1})$

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{r}+\sqrt{r}}$ and $r-1<r<r+1$.

Comment: I'd be curious to see a full method that uses this hint.

Comment: **Subhint:** What are $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}+\sqrt{r-1}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}+\sqrt{r}}$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = \frac1{\sqrt x}$, and $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing. Then this inequality holds:

$$\int_{r-1}^rg(x)\ dx > 1\cdot g(r) > \int_{r}^{r+1}g(x)\ dx\\
\int_{r-1}^r\frac{dx}{\sqrt x} > \frac{1}{\sqrt r} > \int_{r}^{r+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}\\
2(\sqrt r - \sqrt{r-1}) > \frac{1}{\sqrt r} > 2(\sqrt{r+1} - \sqrt r)$$

Comment: A very insightful solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt x$. By mean value theorem, there exist $q\in (r-1,r)$ and $s \in (r, r+1)$ that satisfy
$$f(r) - f(r-1) = f'(q),\quad f(r+1)-f(r) = f'(s).$$

By the concavity of $f$, since $q<r<s$,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f'(q) >& f'(r) &> f'(s)\\
f(r)-f(r-1) >& f'(r) &> f(r+1) - f(r)\\
\sqrt{r}-\sqrt{r-1} >& \dfrac1{2\sqrt r} &> \sqrt{r+1} - \sqrt{r}\\
2(\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r}) <& \dfrac1{\sqrt r} &< 2(\sqrt{r} - \sqrt{r-1})
\end{array}$$